# updating object props with given users id context api react

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers, react-context

I'm trying to update a users data with context API - I got it working so it does it individually given their userId - so in this sense

If I want to update the users' avatar image I can do

```js
case 'UPDATE_USER_AVATAR':
      const { userId, avatar } = action.user

      const user = {
        ...state.users.find((c: User) => c.userId === userId),
        avatar,
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map((c: User) => {
          return c.userId !== userId ? c : user
        }),
      }
```

And I update the users' name like this

```js
case 'UPDATE_USER_NAME':
      const { user_id, name } = action.user

      const userName = {
        ...state.users.find((c: User) => c.userName === user_id),
        name,
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map((c: User) => {
          return c.userName !== user_id ? c : userName
        }),
      }
```

This does the job for me but now I am having trouble adding more stuff - for example, I would like to add maybe change the phone number of the user or something - I have to create another new reducer for that - is there a way I can do this all in literally one reducer instead of creating multiple for different cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write only one function to update user infor like this:

```
case 'UPDATE_USER':
  const { user_id, ...userInfor } = action.user

  return {
    ...state,
    users: state.users.map((c: User) => {
      return c.userName !== user_id ? c : {...c, ...userInfor}
    }),
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructure your `action.user` like this.

```js
const { user_id, ...other } = action.user
```

Then create a *user* object like this.

```js
const user = {
  ...state.users.find((c: User) => c.userName === user_id),
  ...other 
};
```

Finally, pass it to `map` as usually.

```js
return {
  ...state,
  users: state.users.map((c: User) => {
    return c.userName !== user_id ? c : user // Pass user object to here.
  }),
}
```

Now you can pass any information about users as you wish.

If you need more information about JavaScript Destructuring, refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Let me know if you need further support.